# error: Traceback (most recent call last): line 58, in <module> msg_dict_count = int(input().strip()) EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code for a hackerrank exercise that accepts a dictionary msg_dict with key map, an integer representing the no_of_messages, and the list of messages to be decoded. The function returns a list of the decoded messages without spaces.

However i am getting this error and im not sure how to resolve it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/submission/20221104/11/52/hackerrank-cc4efe99dc145dc161f1a763dbcdf2e1/code/Solution.py", line 56, in <module>
    msg_dict_count = int(input().strip())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

This is what i was expecting when the code runs

Sample Input 0

9
r 5
l 7
w 3
h 1
d 0
u 4
o 9
y 2
e 6
2
d h y u y r w u u r
y h w e u h e h d d
Sample Output 0

hello
world

Anyways here is my code

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

#
# Complete the 'decode_messages' function below.
#
# The function is expected to return a LIST_OF_STRINGS - the list of decoded messages.
# The function accepts the following parameters:
#  1. DICTIONARY msg_dict - the dictionary to be used to decode each character
#  2. INTEGER no_of_messages - the number of messages in the list to be decoded
#  3. LIST_OF_STRINGS messages - the list of messages with each character (in each message) separated by space
#

 

# Write your code here
def decode_messages(msg_dict,no_of_messages,messages):
    decodeList=[]
    for i in range(no_of_messages):
        decodeList.append([])
        for j in range(0,len(messages[i]),2):
            if messages[i][j+1]!='':
                decodeList[i].append(msg_dict[messages[i][j]]+msg_dict[messages[i][j+1]]) #add consecutive characters of messages
    return decodeList
n=int(input())
msg_dict={} #storing pair consisting of letter and key
messages=[]
for i in range(n):
    a,b=input().split()
    msg_dict[a]=int(b)
no_of_messages=int(input())
for i in range(no_of_messages):
    messages.append(input().split())
decoded_list=decode_messages(msg_dict,no_of_messages,messages)
keys=list(msg_dict.keys())
values=list(msg_dict.values())
decodedMsgs=""
for i in decoded_list:
    for j in i:
        decodedMsgs=decodedMsgs+keys[values.index(j)] #get key corresponding to 
    print(decodedMsgs)
    decodedMsgs=""
    
   
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
   fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

   msg_dict_count = int(input().strip())

   msg_dict = {}

   for _ in range(msg_dict_count):
       key_val = input().rstrip().split()
       msg_dict[key_val[0]] = key_val[1]

   messages_count = int(input().strip())

   messages = []

   for _ in range(messages_count):
       messages_item = input()
       messages.append(messages_item)

   decoded_msgs = decode_messages(msg_dict, messages_count, messages)

   fptr.write('\n'.join(decoded_msgs))
   fptr.write('\n')

   fptr.close()
```

Comment: How are you starting your program. The error indicates that input() cannot read any data, so stdin of the program might not be bound to a tty.

Comment: what do you mean by tty?

Comment: A terminal - something that takes input from the user's keyboard.

Comment: oh i dont think i need to take input i just need to complete the function and return the list of strings but i am stuck

Comment: Then, why are you calling [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)